# Search Hex substring in string

Tags: c++, string, find, hex, substring

Well i got a socket that receives binary data and I got that data into an string, containing values and strings values too. (for example "0x04,h,o,m,e,....")

How can i search for an hex substring into that string?

I.e. i want to search "0x02,0x00,0x01,0x04".

I'm asking for a c++ version of python 'fooString.find("\x02\x00\x01\x04")'

Thanks to all :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good documentation for string is here:
http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/basic_string.html

Hex tokens are passed just like Python (Where do you think Python got the syntax from).
The character \x?? is a single hex character.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


int main()
{
    std::cout << (int)'a' << "\n";
    std::string             x("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPabcdefghijklmnop");
    std::string::size_type  f   = x.find("\x61\x62");   // ab


    std::cout << x.substr(f);

    // As pointed out by Steve below.
    //
    // The string for find is a C-String and thus putting a \0x00 in the middle
    // May cause problems. To get around this you need to use a C++ std::string
    // as the value to find (as these can contain the null character.
    // But you run into the problem of constructing a std::string with a null
    //
    // std::string  find("\0x61\0x00\0x62"); // FAIL the string is treated like a C-String when constructing find.
    // std::string  find("\0x61\0x00\0x62",3); // GOOD. Treated like an array.

    std::string::size_type f2 = x.find(std::string("\0x61\0x00\0x62",3));
}
```

Comment: The only minor issue here is creating an std::string instance that includes a null character, for Ragnagards example string. To do that, you need the std::string constructor that takes a character array and a length...

size_t pos = fooString.find(std::string ("\x02\x00\x01\x04", 4));

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of find options in c++ String object , Like

**find**               Find content in string (public member function)

**rfind**              Find last occurrence of content in string (public member function)

**find_first_of**      Find character in string (public member function)

**find_last_of**       Find character in string from the end (public member function)

**find_first_not_of**  Find absence of character in string

**find_last_not_of**   Find absence of character in string from the end (public member function)

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/

Go to above link and see which suits you

Comment: Find almost match my needs perfectly but how can i turn the hex values list into an string to pass as param to "find"?

thanks

Comment: use stringstream to construct your input param

Comment: and as for the literal string you are searching for, use the very same syntax as in Python:  string sSearchPattern = "\x02\x00\x01\x04";   (note that python strings are more akin to C++ strings than c strings.  The latter are nul-terminated and hence cannot contain any nul character within the string proper.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try [strstr()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strstr/) or a related function. Or you can use something like [strtok](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strtok/) to grab the values between your delimiters and decode it yourself.

Comment: The problem is that strstr() and other c string functions work on c strings which are nul terminated, and therefore do not work with the OP's sample search string.

Comment: He said he was pulling the data from his stream into a string within which he was wanting to search. I assumed he was null terminating as he made that conversion.

Comment: strtok() is a bad idea as it modified the underlying data to keep track of its current location.

Comment: @John D. The problem is not so much the addition of a null terminator to the string, but the fact that the string to search for is a binary string which has 0x00 in second position, and the input is also binary and may include nuls anywhere in the string.  Such strings cannot be handled with c-style strings (and hence with strstr()), you need a c++ string:: which can then perform the needed task with the various search methods of this class.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
char find[] = {0x02, 0x04, 0x04, 0x00};
int pos = strstr(inputStr, find);
```

Just remember, `0x00` is null, i.e. end of string. So if your source or your search contains them, you won't find what you're looking for because `strstr` will stop at the first null.